# How to express a quadratic objective in Docplex on python

Tags: python, cplex, docplex

If any one could help ,I can't express the objective function, this is my code:

```
import numpy as np
def portfolio_return( weights, returns):
    return weights.T @ returns

def portfolio_vol( weights, covmatrix):
    return np.sqrt(weights.T @ covmatrix @ weights)

def sharp_ratio(er,covmat,w,rf = 0.01):
    r_p = portfolio_return(w, er)/100
    sigma_p = portfolio_vol(w,cov)/100
    return (r_p-rf)/sigma_p

w = mdl.integer_var_list(5,5,30, 'w')
mdl.add_constraint(mdl.sum(w) == 100)
mdl.minimize(-sharp_ratio(quartered_er, cov,np.array(w)))
```

But i get this error:

> loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type QuadExpr which has
> no callable sqrt method

Answer (score 0):

You may use numpy for some computation after the solve but the constraints should be described with functions from docplex.

For instance, the quadratic example from the [making optimization easy with python](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/making-optimization-simple-python-alex-fleischer/) story

```
from docplex.mp.model import Model

mdl = Model(name='buses')
nbbus40 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus40')
nbbus30 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus30')
mdl.add_constraint(nbbus40*40 + nbbus30*30 >= 300, 'kids')
mdl.minimize(nbbus40**2*500 + nbbus30**2*400)

mdl.solve()

for v in mdl.iter_integer_vars():
    print(v," = ",v.solution_value)

import numpy as np
print("We bring ",np.array(
    [40,30])@np.array([nbbus40.solution_value,nbbus30.solution_value])
      ," kids to the zoo")
```

gives

```
nbBus40  =  4.0
nbBus30  =  5.0
We bring  310.0  kids to the zoo
```

Comment: Thank you Alex for replay, I still have a problem because the solver look for w as list and the objective function use w.T which is note possible to compute if w is not an array. Could you please give me another suggestion?

Comment: I removed w.T from the objectif function and i get this error : Cannot raise 0.000w_0^2+0.000w_0*w_1+0.000w_0*w_2+0.000w_0*w_3+0.000w_0*w_4+0.000w_1^2+0.000w_1*w_2+0.000w_1*w_3+0.000w_1*w_4+0.000w_2^2+0.000w_2*w_3+0.000w_2*w_4+0.000w_3^2+0.000w_3*w_4+0.000w_4^2 to the power 0.5. A variable's exponent must be 0, 1 or 2.

Comment: is it because w is declared as a list : w = mdl.integer_var_list(5,5,30, 'w')

Comment: Model.minimize accepts linear or quadratic expressions, there is no square root operator in Docplex (in any CPLEX API, actually). Quadratic expressions can be formed by multiplication of linear expressions or power expressions as in x**2.